# How Do You Debug A specific Activity In Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, kotlin

I happen to be a newbie in programming , specifically Mobile App Programming and the programming IDE i usw is Android Studio. so, i have been asking, is it possible for someone to debug just one part of the program, say a single activity , without necessarily having to include the whole project? i have finished the splash screen and i want to debug the ONboarding fragment part only. how can i skip the splash screen and just debug the Onboarding?

Comment: What do you mean by "having to include the whole project"?

Comment: by project, i mean something consisting of many activities and XML all adding up to one application. but here's the thing, i don't want to necessarily debug everything. i only need to debug a specific activity and run it, without having to navigate through the others to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start specific activity by creating specific configuration for it.
here is three steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

one last thing to remember is that you might need to add exported = true, in manifest to that specific activity